# Adding weights to forest plot with subgroups

Tags: r, meta-analysis, weights

I am creating a forest plot with subgroups (roughly following [this](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups)) example).

Now I want each subgroups to be weighted as if I would plot them individually in a separate forest plot, and the weights should be the default weights designed by Viechtbauer et al in the metafor package. The example above does not incorporate separate weights.

The random effects models I used are coded as follows:

```
res <- rma.uni(yi, vi, weights = TRUE, data=SBdomain.total, slab = paste(author, year, sep = ", "), method = "REML")
res
```

My code for the forest plot is as follows:

```
forest(res, xlim=c(-12,8), at=log(c(0.25, 0.50, 1.00, 2.00, 4.00, 8.00)), atransf = exp, cex = 0.8, font = 1, ylim = c(-1, 27), rows=c(3:4, 7:7, 10:21, 23:23), xlab = "Relative risk (log scale)", mlab = "")
```

But when I add weighted = TRUE / or weights = TRUE I get the following error

> message: 1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   "weights" is not a graphical parameter

I also tried the command psize but since it only takes numeric arguments that didn't seem to help a lot.

The polygons are all exactly the same in size. 
Does anyone have an idea how I could add an argument so that the polygons are drawn in size according to their weight in the analysis?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Help with R code is off-topic here but before you ask on the R mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// try removing the weighted argument altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I already removed weights before asking but the result is the same.

Comment: And I am generally interested if there's any possibility to add weight related sizes of the polygons to the subgroup forest plots, since it seems to be standard for all subgroup forest plots I found in any meta-analyses that the polygons are not graphically weighted. Maybe an idea for a package update for the forest function?

Comment: What is the value of $I^2$?

Comment: I-squared = 61.46 % for all studies; when I plot the results as a forest plot with no subset analyses the weights = TRUE argument works.

Comment: In `rma.uni()`, the `weights` argument is not a logical, but meant to indicate custom weights. By setting this is `TRUE`, this gets converted to `1` and so all studies are given equal weight. See `help(rma)`. Also, `forest()` does not have a `weights` or `weighted` argument. Did you mean the `showweights` argument? See `help(forest.rma)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, Wolfgang, your input solved the problem. For anyone that's interested: I removed the weights=TRUE argument from `res <- rma.uni(yi, vi, weights = TRUE, data=SBdomain.total, slab = paste(author, year, sep = ", "), method = "REML")`and then just coded the forest plot as mentioned in the original post. Each individual study is now weighted with "default" weights of the metafor package. If you want to weigh studies individually (eg. by study size), use the weights argument, as mentioned by Wolfgang. Thank you again!